# SQLiteConnection.Open() terminates Windows Forms application without throwing exception

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am having a problem when trying to debug an windows forms application in Visual Studio 2012. When I build and run the program, it exits upon executing the line indicated in the code segment below. It doesn't give me any kind of error, or throw any kind of exception. It just dies and ends without giving me ANYTHING I can use to find out what's wrong.

Here is the class in which it happens when I step through the program execution:

```
public class DBAdapter
{
    protected static SQLiteConnection dbConnection = null;

    protected static void initConnection() {
        dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalData"].ConnectionString);
    }

    protected static void openConnection() {
        if (dbConnection == null)
            initConnection();
        if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            closeConnection();
        else if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            return;
        dbConnection.Open();//<-- Here is where it dies
    }

    protected static void closeConnection() {
        if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            return;
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: "No exception/error" really seems .. suspect.

Comment: Looks like you are not happy with my answer, I give you working example, your question is not well structure and also what this means it dies. For what you are using this connection in what kind of contest and so on ... I wrote you better design in which you don't make checks if the connection is open or closed or whatever. Like I said, you are not satisfied no problem I'm deleting my answer. Good luck with your problem !

Comment: @mybirthname You sound kind of of offended. I'm sorry if you were. I was just trying to clarify the question, and point out why your answer wasn't working, for you or others who might **have** an answer. You shouldn't have deleted your answer for that reason, even if it wasn't an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @mybirthname By the way, I DID try your solution, and it didn't work. the program still terminated on the call to `someSQLiteConnectionObject.Open()`

Comment: If you wrap it in a try/catch, does it catch anything?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Nope. *sigh* Good question, but I tried that, and it doesn't.

Comment: You could check your windows event log (Event Viewer, Windows, Application) and see if the error is reported there. Are you sure your connection-string is being loaded, and is valid?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Can't find anything in logs, but here is the connection string:

data source="C:\Users\PerrinL\AppData\Local\CardShark\CardShark.PCShark\1.0.0.0\Data\LocalCardData.db"

And yes, that file DOES exist.

Comment: So, just to be clear - *when* the VS debugger is attached *and* a break-point is added to the "Open" line, the debugger *does* stop there and then the entire process (including the debugger) terminates when *stepping over* the "Open" line?

Comment: Try `Data Source=C:\Users\PerrinL\AppData\Local\CardShark\CardShark.PCShark\1.0.0.0\Data\‌​LocalCardData.db; Version=3` - capitals might matter, quotes might be disallowed, version might be required. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: OooooKaaaaay Hmm... This is one of those supremely irritating _"It suddenly started working for absolutely no reason"_ scenarios. It suddenly started getting past `Open()`, and now I'm finding that Visual Studio refuses to stop on exceptions, and keeps exiting without so much as a burp, so that the ONLY way I can see what's going on is to wrap EVERYTHING in `try`s and put a breakpoints on all the `catch`es. As for your question @user2864740, yes. That's EXACTLY what was happening, and I DID make ABSOLUTELY sure then that it REALLY wasn't throwing anything like it is now.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I did add caps, semicolon, and `Version=3;`. That may be what did it, and may be our best bet for an answer. I had originally left those out because the entity framework tools for SQLite had added a connection string automatically that looked like what I originally had. If that IS the problem, then shame on the creators of that package.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have gotten this to work, and since no one has provided a definitive answer about why it was not working, I will post my best guess as to what did the trick in order to wrap this up and hopefully provide a hint for others who have this problem. (See comments to the question also)

I'm not 100% certain that this is what did it, since it's not the only thing that changed when the project started working, but I took Blorgbeard's advice from the comments and changed the connection string:

```
data source="C:\Users\PerrinL\AppData\Local\CardShark\CardShark.PCShark\1.0.0.0\Data\‌​LocalCardData.db"
```

became

```
Data Source=C:\Users\PerrinL\AppData\Local\CardShark\CardShark.PCShark\1.0.0.0\Data\‌‌LocalCardData.db; Version=3
```

Added caps to `data source`, removed quotes from the file path and put a `;` after it, and added `Version=3;`

I hope that helps someone.